# append nodelist to a node

Tags: java, xml

i'm adding Nodes from a NodeList to an XML document, however it only inserts the first node.
Here is the piece of code that adds the node :

```
Element root = doc.createElement("Affaires");
doc.appendChild(root);
for (int i = 0; i < a_copier.getLength(); i++) { 
        root.appendChild(a_copier.item(i));
    }
```

`a_copier`is the NodeList and it contains two items

Thanks in advance

Comment: If "root" is the actual Root Node of your XML document, you can't add arbitrary nodes to it: it's supposed to contain processing directives and so on, and the document element. You have to add a single document Element (with some name) and then add your content nodes to that.

Comment: thank you for your response 
you see i have already added "root" manually as an element (i edited my question), so i'm not sure if that's what you meant. Excuse my noobness